# Excel 2016 is asking for a password for running a VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've provided a password to unprotect active sheet to perform a Macros but still, it is asking a password to perform some parts of it (1) For changing case to Uppercase and (2) for clearing contents. I don't know why? Could you help me where I am wrong! My code is -

```
Sub REFRESH_DATA()
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="****"
Set rng = Range("A8:R" & last)
last = Range("B99000").End(xlUp).Row

With rng.Borders  ' Blue border
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = vbBlue
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

If Range("B8") <> "" Then   ''''''' Upper case''''''
    ActiveSheet.Range("B8:L21000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
  With Selection
    .Value = UCase(.Value)
  End With
End If

Range("A" & last + 1 & ":R" & 90000).ClearContents

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="****"

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of Popup screen asking for password]

Comment: Are you sure the first bit is actually working? The bit with the `Rng` object? Because the very strange thing is that you're populating `last` AFTER you've already used it to declare a range...

Comment: Which line gives the error? If it's the `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` line, the password is likely just wrong. If it's any other line, you need to explicitly qualify the calls to `Range` instead of using the implicit `ActiveSheet`. We *know* it's before `.Value = UCase(.Value)`, because that's a type mismatch error - you can't pass an array to `UCase` like that.

Comment: To summarize: First, double check that your password is indeed correct. Then, you need to calculate the last row **before** using it to declare a range (swap those lines). Then, you need to properly qualify your objects (ranges) with a worksheet. This will work fine when you run it from the sheet that houses the code, but if you switch sheets and run the code, you will be referencing different worksheets (the sheet that houses the code and the `ActiveSheet`). Last, you will need to loop through some defined range ( or array) and convert each cell to `UCase` individually.

Comment: Yes, it is working.

The password is correct and the above code is working fine when I use it without a password.

To find out the error, I made many changes and try, swapping of 'last' and 'rng' lines is one of them. On error when I click on debug option  <.Value = UCase(.Value)> highlighted by yellow colour means the problem is only in this part.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question you have to:

1)unprotect all the sheet
example

```
dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
Next ws
```

'your code and active the sheet with the name
example

```
Worksheets(sheetname).Activate
```

and as last operation protect all sheets

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:=pwd
Next ws
```

Hope this helps